# Can't access control panel

Tags: admin, deployment

I moved my website from local to an online test server via git.

Everything works fine, except that I can

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That error is not really related to Craft, but to your test server's environment.

Your php.ini file is trying to load an `opcache.so` module, but it can't find that module on the server's file system.

Once you correct that, this particular error will go away.